# vbscript to monitor backup group

Tags: vbscript

I have a zero knowledge in `VB scripting`. How can I create a VB script to monitor my backup job status?

The plan is to run a script to check the job status information from the log file. For example in `C:\Program Files\App\Logs.` Normally the status will show like this in the log file `"Group completed, Total 4 client(s), 0 Clients disabled, 0 Hostname(s) Unresolved, 1 Failed, 3 Succeeded, 0 CPR Failed, 0 CPR Succeeded."`

the script will stop once the group completed.

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. A basic knowledge of your language of choice and an effort to solve the problem yourself are the minimum requirements here.

Answer (score 0):

VBScript has access to the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` library which contains features allowing scripts to read from files.

Assuming all you need to do is read from a file, then you're all-set. I don't believe that VBScripts can subscribe to File System notifications, however.

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim logFileStream
Set logFileStream = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Path\to\log.txt")
...
```